# How to call a secured SOAP service using Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

I am working on Spring Integration for calling a SOAP services. Anyhow I am able to call a SOAP service through outbound gateways and I am receiving the response. But now I need to call a SOAP service which is secured. How to call this using Spring Integration. Can anyone help me out in this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi user1957631, what do you mean by "secured"? Is it secured using HTTPS or does it need authentication with BASIC or DIGEST auth or anything like that? Have you tried calling the secured service and received any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a relatively old thread, I thought it might be useful to share the following details for future visitors.

To invoke a secured web service using Spring Integration's web service outbound gateway, you can set the `interceptor` attribute of the gateway bean to point to an interceptor bean which you will have to specify. An example below using plain text password:

```
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
    <property name="securementUsername" value="${ws-user}" />
    <property name="securementPassword" value="${ws-password}" />
    <property name="securementPasswordType" value="PasswordText" />
```

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="yourWebServiceGateway"
        uri="${ws-uri}"
        interceptor="wsSecurityInterceptor" />
```

Note that `spring-ws-security` and Apache's `wss4j` libraries will be required for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration uses [Spring Web Services](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) for the web service support; refer to [its documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#client) for advanced configuration.